# WebSphere variables into WebLogic

Tags: websphere, weblogic

in WebSphere there's a section about WebSphere variables, that are available inside the Java code of any web application.

Is there a similar section into Oracle WebLogic?

thanks

Comment: What kind of variables? Stuff like `weblogic.domainDir` and `weblogic.Name` can be pulled out of system properties but the question's not specific enough to know what you want

Comment: any kind of user variables. For example I'd like to declare a variable MYVAR with a String value like a file system path, and use it on my web applications, so if I want to change it I don't have to modify and redeploy the project.

Comment: You can declare it as a system property, an environment variable, or make your own config/.properties file. Any of those will work.

Comment: Yes, i solved thanks, I had only the Admin Server, so I created another Server, and add in Server->Startup->Arguments -DmyVar=myValue